# PDFTron Trigger Editing of Annotation for annotations when added

Tags: pdftron

I have added a custom annotation and listened to annotationAdded event and select the annotation using below code.

```
instance.docViewer
.getTool("AnnotationCreateCustomStamp")
.on('annotationAdded', 
    function (a) {
        instance.annotManager.selectAnnotation(a);
    });
```

How should I trigger the edit mode on the annotation?

[image: NotesPanel Popup]

[image: Edit Mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your 'AnnotationCreateCustomStamp' tool look like? Does it trigger an 'annotationAdded' action and get to your callback function?

You can open the note panel and start editing with the ['focusNote'](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/WebViewerInstance.html#focusNote__anchor) API

```
instance.docViewer.getTool("AnnotationCreateCustomStamp").on('annotationAdded', 
  function (a) {
    // assuming the code get here
    instance.focusNote(a.Id);
  })
);
```

**Update:**
For focusing on replies of selected annotations, you can use the [getSelectedAnnotations](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/CoreControls.AnnotationManager.html#getSelectedAnnotations__anchor) method and do something like

```
instance.focusNote(docViewer.annotationManager.getSelectedAnnotations()[0].Id)
```

Or you can use the [annotationSelected](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/annotation-events#annotationselected) event and do something like

```
WebViewer(
{
  // your configuration
}, document.getElementById('viewer'))
.then(function(instance) {
  const { annotManager } = instance;
  annotManager.on('annotationSelected', (annots) => {
    if(annots && annots[0]) {
      instance.focusNote(annots[0].Id);
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: On a side note:

instance.annotManager.selectAnnotation(a);
instance.annotationPopup.store.dispatch({
    type: 'SET_NOTE_EDITING',
    payload: { isNoteEditing: true },
});
This also worked for me on the latest version from github.

Comment: Also another question, do you know how to focus on reply for selected annotation?

Comment: I updated my answer with how to focus on selected annotations